# how to retrieve data by index in php

Tags: php

i have data in this

```
 "method": [
        {
          "id": "626",
          "rating": "936.6"
        },
        {
          "id": "631",
          "rating": "332"
        }
      ]
```

I made a loop, in this script.. and I want to retrieve rating data based on index
because there is a special need, how?

```
<?php foreach($res['method'] as $key=>$row) { ?>    
   
    <?php echo [0]['rating']; ?> // rating index 0
    <?php echo [1]['rating']; ?> // rating index 1
    //I retrieve data by index this way but error Undefined index: rating

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $row['rating']; ?>`

Comment: Are you asking how to pick out a rating for a specific id?

Comment: Can you add a small input / desired output example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to access an array by an index, you have to write the array variable name first. Example: `$res['method'][0]`
You also don't need that `foreach` loop if you just access the array by indexes, no more. You don't even need `$key`.

Answer (score 0):

In the following the indexes of the rows aren't referenced.  You can just loop through a collection, and pick out the attributes you want.

```
<?php

$rows = 
[
    [
        'name' => 'Bob',
        'occupation' => 'Builder'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Pat',
        'occupation' => 'Postie'
    ]
];

foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
    echo $row['name'], ' is a ', $row['occupation'], ".\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Bob is a Builder.
Pat is a Postie.
```